# Should date formats be specified in SQL statements?

Tags: oracle, sql-injection

I see code from developers using implicit date conversion.  I would like a definitive answer to why they should not do this.

```
SELECT * from dba_objects WHERE Created >= '06-MAR-2012';
```

Comment: Do you have some examples?

Comment: @Frustrated Added an example.

Comment: I would even go so far that you should not use abbreviated month names either unless NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE parameter is used as well in a to_date() call

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `'2012/12/1'` in the US is 11 months after the same string date in Europe.

Allowing implicit conversions means you are at the mercy of location settings.

If you can name a business where 11 months is an acceptable margin of error I'll be impressed.

Comment: Indeed, '01/01/11' could be 10 years off. +1

Comment: @LeighRiffel: Or even 110 years off...

Comment: +1, one should never rely on implicit DATE conversion (or any implicit data type casting that is)

Comment: "name a business where 11 months is an acceptable margin of error" -- genealogy engines tend to allow two years either side of the input year when searching registers.

Comment: @onedaywhen good answer - as stated, I'm impressed!

Comment: @LeighRiffel - Or 2000 years off.  I've seem *many* times where dates entered with 2 digit years were interpreted as first century AD because `YYYY` was part of the format mask that was eventually used.  That works for a while when people are generally only displaying 2 digit years but then someone starts to sort data or display it using 4 digit years and everything gets hinkey.

Answer (score 14):

There are problems that will occur if a session with a different date format runs the code.

**Statement Failure**

```
DROP TABLE t1;
CREATE TABLE t1 AS (SELECT sysdate mydate FROM dual WHERE 1=2);
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MON-DD-RR';
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('01-02-12');
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

**Bad Data**

```
  DROP TABLE t1;
  CREATE TABLE t1 AS (SELECT sysdate mydate FROM dual WHERE 1=2);

  --User 1
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM-DD-RR';
  INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('01-02-11');

  --User 2
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-RR';
  INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('01-02-11');

  --User 3
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'RR-MM-DD';
  INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('01-02-11');

  SELECT to_char(mydate,'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM t1;
```

In this situation because each of the alter/insert statements could be done by different users.  They would all be running the same statements, but the resulting dates would be completely different.  The insert statements might be buried in a package that is only indirectly being called.  Because no error was returned the problem might not be found until much later.

**SQL Injection**

```
  CLEAR SCREEN;
  DROP TABLE Secrets;
  CREATE TABLE Secrets (RevealDate Date, Secret Varchar2(200));
  INSERT INTO Secrets VALUES (trunc(sysdate),   '*** Common Knowledge. ***');
  INSERT INTO Secrets VALUES (trunc(sysdate+1), '*** Don''t Let Anyone know this. ***');

  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ShowRevealedSecrets IS
     vStatement varchar2(200);
     vOutput Varchar2(1000);
     vDate date:=sysdate;
  begin
  vStatement:='SELECT secret FROM Secrets WHERE RevealDate = ''' || vDate || '''';
  execute immediate vStatement INTO vOutput;
  DBMS_Output.Put_Line(vOutput);
  END;
  /

  --Normal Use.     
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YY';
  EXEC ShowRevealedSecrets();

  --Explointing SQL Injection
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = '"'' OR RevealDate > sysdate--"';
  EXEC ShowRevealedSecrets();
```

In this situation a malicious individual could alter there sessions date format in such a way as to give them access to data that they would not normally have access to.

Comment: +1 but I think the SQL injection case is pretty narrow.

Comment: @JNK I agree, and that makes it all the more likely to be missed in a code review.

Comment: Off-topic, but this SQL-injection whitepaper is brilliant: http://www.accuvant.com/capability/accuvant-labs/security-research/lateral-sql-injection-revisited-exploiting-numbers